# Sql Join 2 tables get multiple column data referencing data in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have the 2 tables:

```
Games tbl                       Official tbl
Id    Ref1   Ref2   Ref3       RefId        Name
------------------------       ---------------------
1      1      3      2           1           Jaz
2      2      1      3           2           Rog
3      1      2      3           3           Dan
```

If a game is selected I need to get Ref Names as separate entries for that game, for example:

```
Game 1 - Ref1 = Jaz         Game 2 - Ref1 = Rog
         Ref2 = Dan                  Ref2 = Jaz
         Ref3 = Rog                  Ref3 = Dan
```

I have tried the sql below, but it seems to only get Ref1 and not Ref2 or Ref3:

```
Select a.Ref1, a.Ref2, a.Ref3 
From Games a 
Inner Join Official b On a.Ref1 = b.RefId 
Where a.Id = @Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join `Games` to 3 copies of `Official`:

```
SELECT g.Id,
       o1.Name Name1,
       o2.Name Name2,
       o3.Name Name3
FROM Games g
INNER JOIN Official o1 ON g.Ref1 = o1.RefId
INNER JOIN Official o2 ON g.Ref2 = o2.RefId
INNER JOIN Official o3 ON g.Ref3 = o3.RefId
WHERE g.Id = ?;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8a9870849522a5ce58a25a9c6e8287ce).

Also, you could test correlated subqueries instead of the joins.
 Sometimes they provide better performance:

```
SELECT g.Id,
       (SELECT o.Name FROM Official o WHERE o.RefId = g.Ref1) Name1,
       (SELECT o.Name FROM Official o WHERE o.RefId = g.Ref2) Name2,
       (SELECT o.Name FROM Official o WHERE o.RefId = g.Ref3) Name3
FROM Games g
WHERE g.Id = ?;
```

Comment: pefect. thank you. I thought i tried that before and it didn't work, but you r answer was correct.

Comment: @mlg fine if it worked. Also, test the correlated subqueries in my edited answer. Not so elegant but they may be better for performance in large datasets.

Comment: I will definitely check out the other way. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should join for every reference from official table in your query

```
  Select Ref1, a.Ref2, a.Ref3 From Games a 
    Left Join Official 
       b On a.Ref1 = b.RefId 
       OR a.Ref2 = b.RefId 
       OR a.Ref3 = b.RefId 
    Where a.Id = @Id
```

Comment: The requirement is to get the names from Official and not RefX.

Answer (score 0):

Initially from looking at your desired results with the names on individual rows it looked like you wanted to *unpivot* the data, for which the following query using `cross apply` would have been applicable:

```
select g.id GameId, o.refId, o.Name
from games g
cross apply (values (ref1,1), (ref2,2), (ref3,3))r(refId,seq)
join officials o on o.refId=r.RefId
where g.id=1
order by r.seq;
```

however, it does seem like you are expecting one row per game with three columns, in which case the same is applicable, now with a *pivot* operation also.

You might think this is long-winded compared to the simpler multiple-join option, however for a specific GameId it requires reading each table only *once*.

```
select GameId, 
    Max(case when seq=1 then name end) Ref1,
    Max(case when seq=2 then name end) Ref2,
    Max(case when seq=3 then name end) Ref3
from (
    select g.id GameId, o.refId, o.Name, r.Seq
    from games g
    cross apply (values (ref1,1), (ref2,2), (ref3,3))r(refId,seq)
    join officials o on o.refId=r.RefId
    where g.id=1
)g
group by GameId;
```

[working example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62f3faefe0a84b94dfae5630cfd37faa)